# Removing all the vowels from a string - PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this homework assignment :

```
 Write an anonymous PL/SQL block that accepts a string as input and removes all of the vowels (a.e.i.o.u) from the string, then outputs the results.

 The output should look like this:

 Run the Program

 SQL>@rm_vowels

 Enter the String: A penny for your thoughts

 SQL>****************************

 SQL>The new string is: pnny fr yr thghts
```

And this does look like something really easy to do but I'm really lacking some PL/SQL experience to get this done.

From my searches so far I've realized I need to use something similar to this :

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(name,'[a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U]','')
```

Right ?

Comment: This question would be much more interesting if it dealt with "Y".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the assignment calls for an anonymous pl/sql block, and prompting user for input.  So you'd have something like this:

```
set serveroutput on
set verify off

accept vstring prompt "Please enter your string: ";
declare
   vnewstring varchar2(100);
begin
   vnewstring := regexp_replace('&vstring', '[aeiouAEIOU]','');
   dbms_output.put_line('The new string is: ' || vnewstring);
end;
/
```

You can put this in a file called "my_homework_from_SO.sql" and from the same directory the file is located, login to sqlplus and run it:

@my_homework_from_SO.sql

```
Please enter your string: This is a test
The new string is: Ths s  tst

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the translate function, which might be marginally faster than regexp_replace:

```
select translate('A penny for your thoughts', 'xaeiouAEIOU', 'x') new_str from dual;

NEW_STR           
------------------
 pnny fr yr thghts
```

You may wish to put a trim around to remove any leading/trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` (though you certainly don't need commas in the character class - plus you don't need to replace with anything):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('A penny for your thoughts','[aeiouAEIOU]')
  FROM dual;
```

You can also use the following which might well be more efficient that using regular expressions (and which will work in Oracle 9i or lower, as well):

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('A penny for your thoughts', 'AEIOUaeiou', ' ')
  FROM dual
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this function call should do the trick:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('A penny for your thoughts','[a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U]','')
FROM   dual;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. And sorry for any dumb question as I'm a beginner on this and I'm trying to learn right now so yeah, I understand the select regexp_replace but what do we need the 'FROM dual;' from ?

Comment: And in this case I should be the one inserting the string and not having it passed inside my function right ?

Comment: @NetworkzZz Oracle, unlike other databases, does not support `select`s without a `from` clause. So we use the `dual` dummy table. Wrt the second question - yes - the first argument for `regexp_replace` should be the column/value you want to transform.

Comment: Why the commas in the character class?